# Stata: Replace and rename variable after encode command

Tags: stata

I would like to replace and retain the original variable name after using the `encode` command for a set of variables `x1-xn`.  This is where I've started:

```
for var x*: encode x*, generate(x*_) label(label)
```

My question is: what is a clean way to drop the `x*` (original string) variables?

When I figure that out, I can execute this command to `rename x*_` (the new encoded variable):

```
rename x*_ x*
```

Comment: what's the question then?

Comment: please add more information about your problem.

Comment: `for` is not documented in any recent version of Stata. I don't have access at the moment to the documentation for Stata 6 that would be needed to answer how to do it using `for`, but if you are using Stata 7 or later you should switch to `foreach`. If you are using an earlier version, you should say what it is. If you were presenting pseudocode, you should have explained that. Whatever the truth is, this question is inadequately explained. My recollection is that your `for` statement is a long way from legal.

Comment: @NickCox thanks for the input!  I am using Stata 12, but I'm not sure what you mean by pseudocode.  The commands that I posted in the question were those that I've actually used in Stata 12.  My econometrics professor had used the `for` command in this version and it worked, so I did not realize that it was not appropriate.  Could you please clarify what you meant by the pseudocode and legal comments?

Comment: Pseudocode is code that isn't in any particular language. I didn't say that using `for` wasn't appropriate; I said it was not documented, so you rely entirely on some code being remembered from a previous successful use. Clearly you haven't tried looking for the help for `for`, as you would have found that it doesn't exist. As I said, my recollection is that your code isn't legal, meaning would not work because of a syntax error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe you meant something like:

```
clear all
set more off

* example database
sysuse auto
keep make

clonevar make2 = make

describe
list in 1/5, nolabel

* what you want
foreach v of varlist make* {
    encode `v', gen(new`v')
    drop `v'
    rename new`v' `v'
}

describe
list in 1/5, nolabel
```

Translated into plain English (although code is straightforward) this is: for each variable that starts with **make**, `encode` it generating a new variable, then `drop` the old one and `rename` the new
one. *Local macros* are used. See `help foreach` and `help macro` for details.

Comment: How about `destring var, replace`?

Comment: `destring` is appropriate if and only if the variables concerned are numeric in content, but happen to be imported as string variables. OP did not indicate that, but it may be true.

Comment: Sorry I didn't make that clear.  The string variables are not numeric in content.  Otherwise, yes, the `destring` command would do this elegantly.